# Interpolate polynomial over a finite field

Tags: python, sympy, polynomial-math, galois-field, finite-field

I want to use python interpolate polynomial on points from a finite-field and get a polynomial with coefficients in that field. 
Currently I'm trying to use SymPy and specifically interpolate (from `sympy.polys.polyfuncs`), but I don't know how to force the interpolation to happen in a specific gf. If not, can this be done with another module?

Edit: I'm interested in a Python implementation/library.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SymPy's [interpolating_poly](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/reference.html#sympy.polys.specialpolys.interpolating_poly) does not support polynomials over finite fields. But there are enough details under the hood of SymPy to put together a class for finite fields, and find the coefficients of [Lagrange polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) in a brutally direct fashion.

As usual, the elements of finite field GF(p<sup>n</sup>) are [represented by polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field#Explicit_construction_of_finite_fields) of degree less than n, with coefficients in GF(p). Multiplication is done modulo a reducing polynomial of degree n, which is selected at the time of field construction. Inversion is done with extended Euclidean algorithm.

The polynomials are represented by lists of coefficients, highest degrees first. For example, the elements of GF(3<sup>2</sup>) are:

```
[], [1], [2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]
```

The empty list represents 0.

#### Class GF, finite fields

Implements arithmetics as methods `add`, `sub`, `mul`, `inv` (multiplicative inverse). For convenience of testing interpolation includes `eval_poly` which evaluates a given polynomial with coefficients in GF(p<sup>n</sup>) at a point of GF(p<sup>n</sup>).

Note that the constructor is used as G(3, 2), not as G(9),  - the prime and its power are supplied separately.

```
import itertools
from functools import reduce
from sympy import symbols, Dummy
from sympy.polys.domains import ZZ
from sympy.polys.galoistools import (gf_irreducible_p, gf_add, \
                                     gf_sub, gf_mul, gf_rem, gf_gcdex)
from sympy.ntheory.primetest import isprime

class GF():
    def __init__(self, p, n=1):
        p, n = int(p), int(n)
        if not isprime(p):
            raise ValueError("p must be a prime number, not %s" % p)
        if n <= 0:
            raise ValueError("n must be a positive integer, not %s" % n)
        self.p = p
        self.n = n
        if n == 1:
            self.reducing = [1, 0]
        else:
            for c in itertools.product(range(p), repeat=n):
              poly = (1, *c)
              if gf_irreducible_p(poly, p, ZZ):
                  self.reducing = poly
                  break

    def add(self, x, y):
        return gf_add(x, y, self.p, ZZ)

    def sub(self, x, y):
        return gf_sub(x, y, self.p, ZZ)

    def mul(self, x, y):
        return gf_rem(gf_mul(x, y, self.p, ZZ), self.reducing, self.p, ZZ)

    def inv(self, x):
        s, t, h = gf_gcdex(x, self.reducing, self.p, ZZ)
        return s

    def eval_poly(self, poly, point):
        val = []
        for c in poly:
            val = self.mul(val, point)
            val = self.add(val, c)
        return val
```

#### Class PolyRing, polynomials over a field

This one is simpler: it implements addition, subtraction, and multiplication of polynomials, referring to the ground field for operations on coefficients. There is a lot of list reversals `[::-1]` because of SymPy's convention to list monomials starting with highest powers.

```
class PolyRing():
    def __init__(self, field):
        self.K = field

    def add(self, p, q):
        s = [self.K.add(x, y) for x, y in \
             itertools.zip_longest(p[::-1], q[::-1], fillvalue=[])]
        return s[::-1]       

    def sub(self, p, q):
        s = [self.K.sub(x, y) for x, y in \
             itertools.zip_longest(p[::-1], q[::-1], fillvalue=[])]
        return s[::-1]     

    def mul(self, p, q):
        if len(p) < len(q):
            p, q = q, p
        s = [[]]
        for j, c in enumerate(q):
            s = self.add(s, [self.K.mul(b, c) for b in p] + \
                         [[]] * (len(q) - j - 1))
        return s
```

#### Construction of interpolating polynomial.

The [Lagrange polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) is constructed for given x-values in list X and corresponding y-values in array Y. It is a linear combination of basis polynomials, one for each element of X. Each basis polynomial is obtained by multiplying `(x-x_k)` polynomials, represented as `[[1], K.sub([], x_k)]`. The denominator is a scalar, so it's even easier to compute.

```
def interp_poly(X, Y, K):
    R = PolyRing(K)
    poly = [[]]
    for j, y in enumerate(Y):
        Xe = X[:j] + X[j+1:]
        numer = reduce(lambda p, q: R.mul(p, q), ([[1], K.sub([], x)] for x in Xe))
        denom = reduce(lambda x, y: K.mul(x, y), (K.sub(X[j], x) for x in Xe))
        poly = R.add(poly, R.mul(numer, [K.mul(y, K.inv(denom))]))
    return poly
```

#### Example of usage:

```
K = GF(2, 4) 
X = [[], [1], [1, 0, 1]]                # 0, 1,   a^2 + 1
Y = [[1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]   # a, a^2, a^3
intpoly = interp_poly(X, Y, K)
pprint(intpoly)
pprint([K.eval_poly(intpoly, x) for x in X])  # same as Y
```

The pretty print is just to avoid some type-related decorations on the output. The polynomial is shown as `[[1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 0]]`. To help readability, I added a function to turn this in a more familiar form, with a symbol `a` being a generator of finite field, and `x` being the variable in the polynomial.

```
def readable(poly, a, x):
    return Poly(sum((sum((c*a**j for j, c in enumerate(coef[::-1])), S.Zero) * x**k \
               for k, coef in enumerate(poly[::-1])), S.Zero), x)
```

So we can do

```
a, x = symbols('a x')
print(readable(intpoly, a, x))
```

and get

```
Poly(x**2 + (a**2 + a + 1)*x + a, x, domain='ZZ[a]')
```

This algebraic object is not a polynomial over our field, this is just for the sake of readable output.

#### Sage

As an alternative, or just another safety check, one can use the [`lagrange_polynomial`](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/polynomial_rings/sage/rings/polynomial/polynomial_ring.html#sage.rings.polynomial.polynomial_ring.PolynomialRing_field.lagrange_polynomial) from Sage for the same data.

```
field = GF(16, 'a')
a = field.gen()
R = PolynomialRing(field, "x")
points = [(0, a), (1, a^2), (a^2+1, a^3)]
R.lagrange_polynomial(points)
```

Output: `x^2 + (a^2 + a + 1)*x + a`

Comment: Thanks! @if.... one comment - calculating the denom doesn't have to be in the loop including d, since its not dependent on it.

Comment: I added a class `PolyRing` , which simplifies the computation of the polynomial.

Comment: Btw this [module](https://github.com/Glank/Galois) (found later) have support for polynomials over GF. But it doesn't have interpolation.

Comment: Overall I think your answer here is a good base for a module which is probably missing in Python.

Comment: Comment - Since this is python, performance is not probably not a goal, but for cases where performance is a goal, Lagrange interpolation can be improved from O(n^3) to O(n^2) with a one time calculation of the product series for all x[i] in O(n^2) time, then taking only O(n) time to divide that poly by (1-x[i]) for each x[i] in the outer loop. Faster still is if the set of x[] values are fixed, in which case the product series can be pre-computed just one time.

Comment: @rcgldr   [All choices result in isomorphic fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field#Non-prime_fields), so I loop over all monic polynomials in a kind of lexicographic order and pick the first that qualifies. This is done at the lines  `for c in itertools.product(range(p), repeat=n):  poly = (1, *c); if gf_irreducible_p(poly, p, ZZ): self.reducing = poly`.

Comment: @rcgldr As written, the code picks a monic irreducible polynomial of degree n. A polynomial does not have to be primitive to be used in the construction of GF(p^n). The method is chosen for simplicity rather than efficiency. For example, to construct GF(2^3) the code loops over x^3, x^3+1, x^3+x, x^3+x+1, stopping at the latter, as it's irreducible. The lexicographic sort favors polynomials with few terms, but does not guarantee that the minimal number of terms will be used.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of the [`galois`](https://github.com/mhostetter/galois) Python library. Polynomial interpolation can be performed with the `lagrange_poly()` function. Here's a simple example.

```py
In [1]: import galois

In [2]: galois.__version__
Out[2]: '0.0.32'

In [3]: GF = galois.GF(3**5)

In [4]: x = GF.Random(10); x
Out[4]: GF([ 33,  58,  59,  21, 141, 133, 207, 182, 125, 162], order=3^5)

In [5]: y = GF.Random(10); y
Out[5]: GF([ 34, 239, 120, 170,  31, 165, 180,  79, 215, 215], order=3^5)

In [6]: f = galois.lagrange_poly(x, y); f
Out[6]: Poly(165x^9 + 96x^8 + 9x^7 + 111x^6 + 40x^5 + 208x^4 + 55x^3 + 17x^2 + 118x + 203, GF(3^5))

In [7]: f(x)
Out[7]: GF([ 34, 239, 120, 170,  31, 165, 180,  79, 215, 215], order=3^5)
```

The finite field element display may be changed to either the polynomial or power representation.

```py
In [8]: GF.display("poly"); f(x)
Out[8]: 
GF([              α^3 + 2α + 1, 2α^4 + 2α^3 + 2α^2 + α + 2,
           α^4 + α^3 + α^2 + α,              2α^4 + 2α + 2,
                   α^3 + α + 1,                   2α^4 + α,
                   2α^4 + 2α^2,       2α^3 + 2α^2 + 2α + 1,
    2α^4 + α^3 + 2α^2 + 2α + 2, 2α^4 + α^3 + 2α^2 + 2α + 2], order=3^5)

In [9]: GF.display("power"); f(x)
Out[9]: 
GF([α^198, α^162, α^116, α^100, α^214, α^137, α^169,  α^95, α^175, α^175],
   order=3^5)
```

Comment: is it possible that this interpolation function is way way slower than vanilla python implementations? I might have done something wrong but its like 20x slower for a test run that I have. I was hoping to make it 20x faster lol

Comment: @popeye can you open a GitHub issue (https://github.com/mhostetter/galois/issues) and I'll take a look? Add the vanilla python example and the galois example.

Comment: Sure, I'll find some time to do it tomorrow

Comment: Performance improvements were added in v0.1.2