# How to work with polynomials over Galois fields in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

How are Galois fields represented in SymPy?  I couldn't find any documentation for this online, but SymPy contains a module called "galoistools", so I thought I should give it a try.  I tried the following experiment:

```
from sympy import *
x = symbols("x")
A = [LC(Poly(i*x, modulus=8) * Poly(j*x, modulus=8)) for i in range(1, 8) for j in range(1, i+1)]
B = [LC(Poly(i*x, domain=GF(8)) * Poly(j*x, domain=GF(8))) for i in range(1, 8) for j in range(1, i+1)]
```

However, the resulting lists `A` and `B` are identical, so I'm obviously misunderstanding how this is supposed to be used.  I'm trying to work in GF(8), i.e. GF(2^3), which is not the same as computing modulo 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At present SymPy does not have support for finite fields other than Z/pZ. The existing class GF(n) is misleadingly named; it actually implements Z/nZ as you observed.

However, using the low-level routines already present in SymPy's [`galoistools`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/internals.html#manipulation-of-dense-univariate-polynomials-with-finite-field-coefficients) module, one can create a class for general finite fields `GF(p^n)` and for polynomials over such a field: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48067397) where these classes are implemented (for the purpose of computing an interpolating polynomial, but they can be used for other things too). This is just a minimal class; it does not interface with advanced polynomial manipulation methods that are implemented in SymPy.

Answer (score 0):

As of November 2023, the previous answer is still correct; the so-called "galoistools" module is still semantically broken—not actually implementing galois fields, but only integer extension rings—[gh-9544](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/9544), [gh-13886](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/13886), and [gh-21104](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/21104).

---

However, in July of 2018, SymPy 1.2 released, with [`sympy.polys.agca.extensions.FiniteExtension`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/agca.html#finite-extensions), which actually *does* offer methods for galois fields, including correct multiplication and inversion.

```py
from sympy import Symbol, PurePoly
from sympy.polys.agca.extensions import FiniteExtension
X = Symbol('X')

# Conway multiplication
F_2_8 = FiniteExtension(PurePoly(X**8 + X**4 + X**3 + X**2 + 1, modulus=2))

# AES multiplication
F_AES = FiniteExtension(PurePoly(X**8 + X**4 + X**3 + X    + 1, modulus=2))

assert F_2_8(X**5 + X) * F_2_8(X**6 + 1) == F_2_8(X**6 + X**3 + X)
assert F_2_8(X**3 + X**2 + X) * F_2_8(X**3 + X**2 + X).inverse() == F_2_8(1)
```

---

It may also be worth noting that `gf_add` works; it's only `gf_mul` (and related methods) that's broken. And it's not even *that* broken; it only neglects the reduction step; so a "correct" `gf_mul` can be *easily* whipped up as follows:

```py
from sympy.polys.domains import ZZ
from sympy.polys.galoistools import gf_degree, gf_irreducible_p, gf_mul, gf_rem

def actual_gf_mul(f, g, p, r, K=ZZ):
    n = gf_degree(r)-1
    assert gf_irreducible_p(r, p, K), f"gf_mul[{p},{n}]: r={r} is not irreducible"
    return gf_rem(gf_mul(f, g, p, K), r, p, K)
```

Comment: What's the "proper" way to convert between representations and field polynomials, like `F_AES(X**7 + X**4 + X**2 + 1) <-> 0b10010101`? It's possible to rig up something that "works" with [`sympy.ntheory.digits`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/ntheory.html#module-sympy.ntheory.digits), but that really seems quite sketchy.

Comment: I'm aware that `r = PurePoly(..., modulus=2)` isn't the most integrated choice for this since [it invokes `old_polynomialring.GlobalPolynomialRing`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/sympy-1.12/sympy/polys/agca/extensions.py#L276), but it's the *only* choice AFAICT because what *should* be the more integrated choice, `r = ring([X], GF(2))[0](...)`, doesn't even work. :(